# using Vim gd on project with multiple code folders

Tags: vim

I am using `vim` to edit `Fortran 90` code. The code is structured in the following manner:
`./srcs` - contains main code file
`./libs` - contains some module file

If I open the main file in `vim` and then find some interesting function and press "gD" `vim` cannot find this function since it does not know where to search. If I copy all the source files to one folder this option does work.

My questions are:

1. How do I tell `vim` where my code is.
2. Can you suggest for a quick manner on how to work with this kind of folder without repeating the use of solution (1).

Comment: Try http://vim.stackechange.com/

Answer (score 2):

In this case you might be better off using [`exuberant ctags`](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).

After installing this program, run `ctags -R` in the top level directory of your project. Then use e.g. `set tags=tags;` in your `.vimrc` to tell vim where your tag file is.

Once this is set up, you can use [tag searching](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html).